# $(this) seems not properly work

Tags: jquery, this, children

I would like to click on a div to make appear his child.
The problem is that I have a long list of those div. Each div has a children.
In the following, I want to click on the div "etiquette" to show or to hide his child div "detail".

```
<div class="etiquette">
  <span class="date">13-07</span>
  <span class="titre">LOREM IPSUM 1</span>
     <div class="detail"><p>lorem ipsum 1</p></div>
</div>
<div class="etiquette">
  <span class="date">14-07</span>
  <span class="titre">LOREM IPSUM 2</span>
     <div class="detail"><p>lorem ipsum 2</p></div>
</div>
<div class="etiquette">
  <span class="date">14-07</span>
  <span class="titre">LOREM IPSUM 3</span>
     <div class="detail"><p>lorem ipsum 3</p></div>
</div>
```

The script I would like to use is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".etiquette").children(".detail").css("display", "none");
    $(this).toggle(function() {
        alert("clicked");
        $(this).children("div.detail").css("display", "block");
    }, function() {
        alert("clicked again");
        $(this).children("div.detail").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

the following works well :

```
$(this).toggle(function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

the following works well, too. But it shows or hide ALL the div "detail" and not only the child of the clicked div :

```
$(this).toggle(function() {
    alert("clicked");
    $(".etiquette").children("div.detail").css("display", "block");
}, function() {
    alert("clicked again");
    $(".etiquette").children("div.detail").css("display", "none");
});
});
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $(this) points to document itself I guess.

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".etiquette").children(".detail").css("display", "none");
  $(".etiquette").click(function(){
    $(this).children("div.detail").toggle();
  });
});
```

I did not tested the code. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".etiquette").children(".detail").css("display", "none");
$('.etiquette').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.detail').toggle();
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x8hDy/)**

There's too much to go into about what's wrong with your code, however if you look at this example you'll see what it does. The first line hides all elements with the class `detail` that are children of elements with the class `etiquette` (which you had and I left unchanged). The next block of code binds the click event to the elements with the class `etiquette` and toggles the display of the child element with the class of `detail`.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
$(this).toggle(function() {
```

to:

```
$('.etiquette').toggle(function() {
```

this `this` refers to the `document` object not `.etiquette` element.

[*note: as of jQuery 1.7 using toggle mouse event has been deprecated.*](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/)

http://jsfiddle.net/f9BcB/

Comment: Might want to note that using this toggle has been deprecated (http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/) whereas the other use of toggle has not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding a toggle function to each div using .each function?

ex:

```
$('.etiquette').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    //Enter toggle function here
  });
});
```